# configure qt to use a custom version of gstreamer

Tags: qt, configuration, gstreamer

I am trying to configure qt `5.6` on my ARM based NVIDIA Jetson Tk1 to use gstreamer version `1.6`, which is located and installed in a folder:

```
/home/luca/gst_1.6
```

What I did was modify was the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `PATH` variables to point to the `/lib` and `/bin` directories respectively of my installation folder.

However, the configuration script picks the system installed gstreamer (version 1.0) rather than the 1.6 version. How may I specify the script as to which gstreamer to pick?

Comment: Are you sure you have linked it correctly? can you display your .pro file. Might it be a runtime issue, have you tried changing the rpath: `QMAKE_LFLAGS += "-Wl,-rpath,/home/luca/gst_1.6/lib"` and also just to see what is already there: `message ("QMAKE_LFLAGS = $$QMAKE_LFLAGS")`

Comment: I am building qt from sources actually. So, it is the configuration script which comes with qt. I will try and update.